# jQuery ScrollTo plugin does not scroll to the element on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollto

I'm using the scrollTo plugin by Ariel Flesler to scroll to an element. However this piece of code just doesn't run on Firefox (v 61).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html, body').scrollTo(document.getElementById('login-link'), 800);
});
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1n26s3dm/1/

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code and make sure you have jQuery installed, because on your fiddle there isn't jquery

```
 $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#login-link").offset().top
        }, 800, function(){

        // this is the callback after the animation is done
        // you can emit events here
        $("#login-link").trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way to also click the element once it has been scrolled to. I tried $("#login-link").click() but it didn't do anything.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the animation-done callback, you can trigger events on any jquery elements while in the callback. If you found my answer useful please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your example on jsfiddle doesn't work. If you need jQuery you should select this library in JS window. Do not use `Resources` for include jQuery.
Try [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/3xmk67fj/2/)

Also try do not mix jQuery and Vanilla.js to work with DOM. Would be better if you  change your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('html, body').scrollTo($('#login-link'), 800);
});
```